# chosen-select shows group label and option select

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

I have chosen select with optdorup and same options, i want to show optgroup label & selected option in chosen select. Pls check my code & suggest changes.
    Check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/x5q95a11

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen();

$(".chosen-select").on('change', function (event,el) {
  var selected_element = $(".chosen-select option:contains("+el.selected+")");
  
  var selected_value  = selected_element.val();
  var parent_optgroup = selected_element.closest('optgroup').attr('label');
  
  selected_element.text(parent_optgroup+' - '+selected_value).trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

<select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" class="chosen-select" tabindex="5">
          <option value=""></option>
          <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
            <option value="Dallas Cowboy">Dallas Cowboys</option>
            <option value="New York">New York Giants</option>
            <option value="Philadelphia">Philadelphia Eagles</option>
            <option value="Washington">Washington Redskins</option>
          <optgroup>
          <optgroup label="NFC NORTH">
            <option value="Dallas Cowboy">Dallas Cowboys</option>
            <option value="New York">New York Giants</option>
            <option value="Philadelphia">Philadelphia Eagles</option>
            <option value="Washington">Washington Redskins</option>
          </optgroup>
          
        </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the option provided by the plugin.
http://jsfiddle.net/kajalc/n1cnc53c/

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({include_group_label_in_selected:true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.min.css">
<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chosen').chosen().change(
        function (evt) {
            var label = $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).closest('optgroup').prop('label');
            alert(label);
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<select class="chosen" style="width:300px;">
    <optgroup label="fruit">
        <option value="1">apples</option>
        <option value="2">pears</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="veg">
        <option value="3">neeps</option>
        <option value="4">tatties</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="omnivore">
        <option value="5">bear</option>
        <option value="6">rats</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a little explanation. What was the issue and how does your code solve it? Or why is your code an improvement?

Comment: It should show fruit-apples, & as per requirment only optgorup label is diffrent options are same

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is what you are expecting. http://jsfiddle.net/kajalc/qnjhb2Lr/

Replace

```
selected_element.text(parent_optgroup+' - +selected_value).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

with

```
 $('.chosen-single>span').text(parent_optgroup + ' - ' + selected_value).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: no not working when i select option from 2nd group, its not showing group lable name, its showing 1st group lable name